# Identifying a sklearn-model's classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

The documentation on [SVMs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) implies that an attribute called `classes_` exists, which allegedly reveals how the model represents classes internally.

I would like to get that information in order to interpret the output from functions like `predict_proba`, which generates probabilities of classes for a number of samples. Hopefully, knowing that given some illustrating values:

```
model.classes_ 
>>> [1, 2, 4]
```

means that I can assume that this holds:

```
model.predict_proba([[1.2312, 0.23512, 6.01234], [3.7655, 8.2353, 0.86323]]) 
>>> [[0.032, 0.143, 0.825], [0.325, 0.143, 0.532]]
```

Probabilities should translate to the same order as the classes, i.e. for the first set of features I can assume:

```
probability of class 1: 0.032
probability of class 2: 0.143
probability of class 4: 0.825
```

But calling `classes_` on an SVM results in an error. Is there a good way to get that information? I can't imagine that it's not accessible any more after the model is trained.

---

edit:
The way I build my model is more or less like this:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion


pipeline = Pipeline([
   ('features', FeatureUnion(transformer_list[ ... ])),
   ('svm', SVC(probability=True))
])
parameters = { ... }
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    pipeline,
    parameters
)

grid_search.fit(get_data(), get_labels())
clf = [elem for elem in grid_search.estimator.steps if elem[0] == 'svm'][0][1]

print(clf)
>> SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
print(clf.classes_)
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/script.py", line 284, in <module>
  File "path/to/script.py", line 181, in re_train
    print(clf.classes_)
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grid_search.estimator` that you are looking at is the unfitted pipeline.
The `classes_` attribute only exists after fitting, as the classifier needs to have seen `y`.

What you want it the estimator that was trained using the best parameter settings, which is `grid_search.best_estimator_`.

The following will work:

```
clf = grid_search.best_estimator_.named_steps['svm']
print(clf.classes_)
```

[and classes_ does exactly what you think it does].

Answer (score 1):

There is a classes field in `sklearn`, it probably means you were calling the wrong model, see example below, we can see that there are classes when looking at the `classes_` field:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> clf = SVC(probability=True)
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
>>> print clf.classes_
[1 2]
>>> print clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]])
[1]
>>> print clf.predict_proba([[-0.8, -1]])
[[ 0.92419129  0.07580871]]
```

Comment: I see. Maybe my problem is, that my model is 'hidden' in a GridSearchCV. I updated the initial post with more information, and a more specific error message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick

```py
arr = model.predict_proba(X)

list1 = arr.tolist()

cls = model.classes_

list2 = cls.tolist()

d = {''Category'':list2,''Probability'':list1[0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)
```